# How can I remove a element and take up its space?

Tags: css, media-queries, hide, visibility

I am using media query to adjust my mobile website. I use the visibility attribute to hide certain elements , but they still take up space.

Please Help!

Comment: Use the display property instead of visibility.

Comment: why would someone put this question negative (-4) ????? wtf , its not a bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `visibility:hidden`. You should use `display:none` instead.

Let me explain the difference

`display:none` indicates that the the element will not appear on the page at all. Additionally, no space will be allocated for it.

`visibility:hidden` is similar to `display:none` in that the element is not visible. However, space is still allocated for it on the page. The element is rendered but isn't seen on the page.

Per W3Schools,

```
Even invisible elements take up space on the page. Use the display property
to create invisible elements that do not take up space
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Answer (score 2):

try `display:none;` as a property